# Spring Cloud Connector and MongoDB Replica Set

Tags: mongodb, spring-cloud, mongodb-replica-set

I have developed a micro service in Spring boot and it is deployed in Cloud Foundry. MongoDB is a service created in PCF and it is a replica set type service. The mongodb service is bound to the micro service in PCF. I am using Spring cloud connector to automatically fetch the connection string for the mongodb service when deployed in cloud using the following code.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("cloud")
public  class CloudFoundryDatabaseConfig extends AbstractCloudConfig{

    @Bean
    public Cloud cloud() {
        return new CloudFactory().getCloud();
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoFactory() {
        return connectionFactory().mongoDbFactory();

    }
}
```

This code is working perfectly fine when the mongoDB service is a standalone type. However if it is a replica set, i get a unknown host exception. Since the mongodb URI contains comma separated host names, it seems to be unresolved.

**An example of MongoDB URI below.**
"mongodb://username:password@101.23.65.41:28000,101.23.65.43:28000,101.23.65.45:28000/default?authSource=admin"

**Error:**
com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongod-node-0-310d0fd1.mongodb.internal: Name or service not known}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException

**Pom.xml:**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-spring-service-connector</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Please help.